# Is it safe to have wheezy sourcs list in Debian Squeeze?

Tags: debian, debian-squeeze, debian-wheezy

Currently, I have a Debian Squeeze 64 bit version installed in my laptop. Since it is said that updates and support for squeeze will be provided only till the next 8 months, and will become unstable after that, will it be safe to continue using it by making a slight change in my machine?

I intend to edit my sources list file and replace all the the squeeze repos to wheezy repos. I will be getting the updates. Right?

Is this safe?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is generally very safe to upgrade Debian from one version to another. However, any upgrade process has some risks, so you may wish to make backups if you're concerned.

The Debian release notes for Wheezy has a [chapter](http://www.debian.org/releases/stable/i386/release-notes/ch-upgrading.html) on upgrading from Squeeze that you may want to read.

Comment: I don't want to upgrade. I just want to get updates for the installed pckages, keeping the current configuration. Is that possible?

Comment: Debian is designed so that you can gradually upgrade from one version to the next. There is no difference between getting "updates for installed packages" and "upgrading" (like you may have seen in Ubuntu or other distros).